# Blazor. Task from another service

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm studying blazor server.
Deployed a solution from a standard vs template.
Created two server-side services, **TestService1** and **TestService2**.

In **TestService1** i have task

```
GetMyData()
```

How can i call with task from TestService2?

If i trying

```
var serv1 = new TestService1()
```

i have to fill in all the variables of the constructor that is in TestService1.

What is easiest way?

Comment: As you are studying, I would suggest you to go through [dependency injection in asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In line with the comment on your question, the best way to go about this in Blazor is to utilize the built-in dependency injection mechanism.

I assume that your services look like the following:

```cs
public class TestService1
{
  public object GetMyData()
  {
  }
}

public class TestService2
{
  private readonly TestService1 _testService1 { get; set; }

  public class TestService2(TestService1 ts1) 
  {
    _testService1 = ts1;
  }

  public void DoesSomething()
  {
    var data = _testService1.GetMyData();
    //...
  }
}
```

First, you'd need to register these with Blazor at startup, so in your `Startup.cs` in the `ConfigureServices` method, add the following, assuming you have an empty constructor available for TestService1:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<TestService1>();
```

Because you'll need to instantiate an instance of `TestService1` into `TestService2` to call methods on it, you'll have to handle registration of `TestService2` differently since you'll need to procure an instance of `TestService1` from the DI service to instantiate it:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<TestService2>(s => {
  var testService1 = s.GetService<TestService1>();
  return new TestService2(testService1);
});
```

It's possible you may need to scope the services differently (e.g. used scoped instead of singletons). You can read about the differences [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Now something is presumably calling `TestService2` to kick all this off, so let's pretend it's running in a component in your Blazor app. You'd inject `TestService2` into the component with the following:

```cs
@inject TestService2 _testService2

<h1>Hello!</h1>

@code {
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    _testService2.DoesSomething();
  }
}
```

As part of the initialization then of this component, it'll automatically inject a `TestService2` instance (based on the scoping you specified at DI initialization) to your component and will call the DoesSomething method on it. When injected, it looks to DI to instantiate the `TestService1` service to the constructor as you've also specified, leaving it free to call that method and the call commences as intended.

Please let me know if you'd like any clarification somewhere!